# React: How to use conditional render and react-hooks to update another component's state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-rendering

I'm new to React. I'm trying to create a Login/Register Screen. I have three components called Login, Register and SlidingCard. I render these componenets on other jsx file called Screen. In SlidingCard.jsx i have a div and inside this div there are some text and button. When i clicked the button, text and button changes to login related things from register related things. Now the part that i stucked. I mentioned that when i clicked the button on SlidingCard the text changes. But with that click i want to render the Login or Register too. How can i do it?

Login.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Input from "./Input";

function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="loginContainer">
      <div className="loginChildContainer">
        <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
        <p>Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</p>
        <Input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
        <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Register.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import FacebookIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Facebook";
import GoogleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Google";
import TwitterIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Twitter";

function Register() {
  return (
    <div className="registerContainer">
      <h1>Create Account</h1>
      <button>
        <FacebookIcon />
      </button>
      <button>
        <GoogleIcon />
      </button>
      <button>
        <TwitterIcon />
      </button>
      <Input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
      <Input type="text" placeholder="email" />
      <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

SlidingCard.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function SlidingCard() {
  const [isChanged, setChange] = useState(false);

  const loginPaheseTexts = {
    title: "Hello, Friend!",
    description: "Enter your personal details and start jurney with us.",
    button: "Sign Up"
  };

  const registerPhaseTexts = {
    title: "Welcome Back",
    description:
      "To keep connecting with us please login with your personal info.",
    button: "Sign In"
  };

  const texts = isChanged ? registerPhaseTexts : loginPaheseTexts;

  function handleClick(event) {
    console.log(isChanged);

    setChange(!isChanged);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{texts.title}</h1>
      <p>{texts.description}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{texts.button}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SlidingCard;
```

Screen.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Login from "./Login";
import Register from "./Register";
import SlidingCard from "./SlidingCard";

function Screen(props) {
  return (
    <div className="appContainer">
      {props.isChanged ? <Register /> : <Login />}
      <SlidingCard />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I checked the interner and i can't find what i'm looking for.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you want to be able to toggle between the `<Register />`  and `<Login />` from something within `<SlidingCard />`?

Comment: You're making some basic mistakes. Apparently Screen is the parent component then how are you getting `isChanged` from the props? If you want to achieve something that you mentioned then you should make a state variable in Screen.jsx, then pass that state to the sliding card as a prop and also use it to show respective Login or Register screens.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to be able to toggle between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `isChanged` state is shared between both rendering `Login/Register` and `SlidingCard`, you need to "lift" that state up to their common parent, `Screen`. Once you do that, you can use `isChanged` directly within `Screen`, and pass it and `setChange` down to `SlidingCard`. [This article](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) from the official React docs explains this issue more.

In the end, you only need to change `Screen.jsx` and `SlidingCard.jsx` like so:

Screen.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Login from "./Login";
import Register from "./Register";
import SlidingCard from "./SlidingCard";

function Screen(props) {
  const [isChanged, setChange] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="appContainer">
      {isChanged ? <Register /> : <Login />}
      <SlidingCard isChanged={isChanged} setChange={setChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Screen;
```

SlidingCard.jsx

```
import React from "react";

function SlidingCard({isChanged, setChange}) {

  const loginPaheseTexts = {
    title: "Hello, Friend!",
    description: "Enter your personal details and start jurney with us.",
    button: "Sign Up"
  };

  const registerPhaseTexts = {
    title: "Welcome Back",
    description:
      "To keep connecting with us please login with your personal info.",
    button: "Sign In"
  };

  const texts = isChanged ? registerPhaseTexts : loginPaheseTexts;

  function handleClick(event) {
    console.log(isChanged);

    setChange(!isChanged);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{texts.title}</h1>
      <p>{texts.description}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{texts.button}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SlidingCard;
```

However, you should also probably consider a more appropriate/readable name for the state, such as `showLogin` and `setShowLogin`.

Comment: When I do it like that, only the SlidingCard component is visible. And when I clicked the button on the component it gives me error says "setChange is not a function". could you help me more?

Comment: @GörkemTandoğan are you sure you are correctly passing the function down to `SlidingCard` and extracting it from props there? Here is a working version of your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-clarke-w0ns04

Comment: I think you were missing `export default` in a few files.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally in React, when you want to change something on the page ... you don't.  Instead, you change a state variable that controls that part of the page, and then React "reacts" by updating the page for you.

So, if you want a Login component to appear, you simply make a `showLogin` state variable, wrap the component with it:

```
{showLogin && <Login/>}
```

and the change that variable to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, I have implemented my suggested changes in a code sandbox project (https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-pond-dwrrnl).

Main changes are in Screen.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Login from "./Login";
import Register from "./Register";
import SlidingCard from "./SlidingCard";

function Screen() {
  const [isChanged, setIsChanged] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="appContainer">
      {isChanged ? <Register /> : <Login />}
      <SlidingCard isChanged={isChanged} setIsChanged={setIsChanged} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Screen;
```

and then get the state as props in Sliding card

```
import React from "react";

function SlidingCard({ isChanged, setIsChanged }) {
  const loginPaheseTexts = {
    title: "Hello, Friend!",
    description: "Enter your personal details and start jurney with us.",
    button: "Sign Up"
  };

  const registerPhaseTexts = {
    title: "Welcome Back",
    description:
      "To keep connecting with us please login with your personal info.",
    button: "Sign In"
  };

  const texts = isChanged ? registerPhaseTexts : loginPaheseTexts;

  function handleClick(event) {
    console.log(isChanged);

    setIsChanged(!isChanged);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{texts.title}</h1>
      <p>{texts.description}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{texts.button}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SlidingCard;
```